# MySQL Duplicate Key on Create Table?

Tags: mysql

Here is my SQL statement for creating table on MySQL, but I got warning says there is duplicate Key (I can't find any one is duplicated?!

```
CREATE TABLE EmployeeSkill (
  empId Integer NOT NULL,
  skillId Integer NOT NULL,
  skillLevel Integer NULL,
  CONSTRAINT empSkillPk PRIMARY KEY(empId, skillId),
  CONSTRAINT empFk FOREIGN KEY(empId) REFERENCES Employee(empId),
  CONSTRAINT skillFk FOREIGN KEY(skillId) REFERENCES Skill(skillId)
)
```

Don't know why... Anyone has any clue?!

Comment: @Harry the problem is I can't find the duplicate in this creation statement.

Comment: @Harry Is during my creating table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it!
I use following statement on my database

```
select *
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS
where CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'FOREIGN KEY'
```

I found that other tables are occupied the foreign key. Just simple use other foreign keys, it would works.

Answer (score 0):

You have primary key in table: `PRIMARY KEY(empId, skillId)`. This error means that combination of inserting `empId` and `skillId` already exists in table. You can check it

```sql
SELECT *
FROM EmployeeSkill
WHERE empId = @insertEmpId AND skillId = @insertSkillId
```

Comment: The problem is I don't have EmployeeSkill table yet, how could that be duplicated?!

Comment: Your are using foreign keys. MySQL will check if parent table has unique index on referenced column. Is `empId` primary key of `Employee`? And `skillId` for `Skill`? If so, in normal case your will not have duplicate values in this columns. But maybe those are not unique/primary keys?